# Are these two theorems about subsequence convergence the same?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the difference between the following theorem and corollary?

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$ $\mathbf{1}:$ If a sequence S of real numbers is convergent to L, then any subsequence of S is also convergent to L
>
> $\mathbf{Corollary}:$ All subsequences of a convergent sequence of real numbers converge to the same limit.

My professor says that theorem 1 doesn't specify whether L is unique, but the following theorem came before the two statements above.

> $\mathbf{Theorem}$ $\mathbf{2}:$ If a sequence S of real numbers is convergent to L, then S cannot also converge to a limit distinct from L

If theorem 2 was already given, wouldn't we know L in theorem 1 is unique? Are there any other differences between the two statements?

Answer (score 1):

More or less the second theorem is the contrapositive of the first one, which would be:

> If two subsequences of $S$ converge to different limits (or any of them is divergent), then $S$ is a divergent series.